# File upload through Postman is faster than through the browser

Tags: file-upload, browser, upload, postman, video-upload

I upload the same video file (145 Mb size) from the same computer to the same server. Upload is done with POST request with multipart/form-data. If I do it with Postman, the upload takes about 30s. If I do it from a browser (tested Chrome, FF, Safari), it takes about a minute.

Postman headers:

```
Cookie: __cfduid=d629ccab89f0d8996cbcd03fd85d7edad1588857074
Postman-Token: <calculated when request is sent>
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=<calculated when request is sent>
Content-Length: <calculated when request is sent>
Host: <calculated when request is sent>
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.24.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
```

Browser headers:

```
:authority: domain.com
:method: POST
:path: /file/add
:scheme: https
accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
cache-control: no-cache
content-length: 145506546
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryWWuN1xlu5NeYmSLR
origin: https://somedomain.com
pragma: no-cache
referer: https://somedomain.com/
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36
```

Does anyone have any idea why upload through browser takes twice more time?